# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at V2Agent.addActionsOnGoogle_

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm creating a chatbot using dialogflow-fulfillment, actions-on-google and hosting it in aws lambda. I'm trying to ask for the user permissions but i am having a problem when i try to add some actions-on-google things, for example permissions.

I've tried what the dialog flow example does here:

https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js

But, since i'm using AWS lambda i didn't follow the exact code maybe i'm missing something.

```
 router.post('/', (request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to the webhook`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  } 

function locationIntent(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv();
    conv.ask(new Permission({
      context: 'To give results in your area',
      permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION',
    }))
    agent.add(conv);
  }

// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);

  if (agent.requestSource === agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE) {
    intentMap.set('location', locationIntent);
  } else {
    intentMap.set(null, other);
  }
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

app.use('/', router);

module.exports = app;
```

I already used this

```
const { WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const { dialogflow,
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  Suggestions,
  Permission,
  UpdatePermission,
  RegisterUpdate,
  Carousel,
} = require('actions-on-google');
```

and my dependencies are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.5.0",
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.3.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dialogflow": "^4.0.3",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0"
  }
```

I take the permission intent from this post in dialogflow blog: 
https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/fulfillment-library-beta/

I checked the logs in my aws-lambda and found this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at
>   V2Agent.addActionsOnGoogle_

This happens when i do `agent.add(conv)`. If i do `agent.add("This is location permission intent");` works. I'm expecting to get the permission and use it later for take some coordinates

i'm using node v10.15.0

Stracktrace from aws-lambda:

```
2019-01-24T12:42:52.013Z    2531e964-1f94-4f41-997a-a4ef14cb55da    TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at V2Agent.addActionsOnGoogle_ (/var/task/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:313:29)
at WebhookClient.addResponse_ (/var/task/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:269:19)
at WebhookClient.add (/var/task/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:245:12)
at locationIntent (/var/task/app.js:75:11)
at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/var/task/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)
at router.post (/var/task/app.js:156:9)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Note: I already tried using other elements from actions on google like carousel and failed. That's makes me thing it's something wrong with the `agent.add` or the `conv`

Comment: I've checked this out https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/149. And tried all the workarounds but nothing :(

Comment: whoops, yeah, that. I pasted the wrong URL. And it was supposed to be fixed with the version you're using. Can you update your question with the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Prisoner i updated the question :) thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That strongly suggests that, despite the dependencies listed, you're using an older version of the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library. Make sure you have the latest versions installed with

```
npm update
```

Comment: Wow that's a bit embarrassing, i'm new using node. Thanks for that that solved it

Comment: Wow! Glad that worked. {: Honestly had me stumped for a bit.

Comment: Ran into this issue on the dialogflow integration editor.. this solution worked for me.